# What are the usage differences between IP addresses that are reserved for private networks?

Tags: networking, ip

I found that

- 192.168.0.0 - 192.168.255.255 (65,536 IP addresses)
- 172.16.0.0 - 172.31.255.255 (1,048,576 IP addresses)
- 10.0.0.0 - 10.255.255.255 (16,777,216 IP addresses)

Then sometimes my computer is assigned a strange IP like 169.254.5.119 which seems also a private network IP address.

My question is, what are the complete list of allocated private network IP ranges and for which purposes are they differing from each other?

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at [Reserved IP addresses](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reserved_IP_addresses) for the full list.

The 169.254.0.0–169.254.255.255 range is meant for link-local adresses (i. e. for hosts to autoconfigure in the lack of a DHCP server): if you boot up a Windows machine in a DHCP-less network, you´ll see that it takes one of those.